# d-regular bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm looking to prove that any $d$-regular bipartite graph satisfies the HALL condition and contains a perfect matching.

I'm having trouble seeing why, if $G=(V,W,E)$, for any $H \subseteq V$, $|H|\leqslant |N(H)|$.

Would appreciate an answer!

Edit: For degree $\geqslant 1$ obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H \subset X$ in an $d$-regular $X,Y$-bigraph $G$.  Let $N(H)$ denote the neighbors of the vertices in $H$.  There are $d\lvert H\rvert$ edges between $H$ and $N(H)$.

If $\lvert N(H)\rvert < \lvert H\rvert$ then $d\lvert N(H)\lvert < d\lvert H\rvert$, so the number of edges between $H$ and $N(H)$ exceeds the number of edges incident with any vertex of $N(H)$, a contradiction.